# What does src="http" do?

Tags: html, http, iframe, src

Let's say I have a normal `iframe` with some standard attributes:

```
<iframe width="300" height="300" src="http"></iframe>
```

What will this `src="http` do? I've seen it around but I don't exactly know what `http` will point to or what this `iframe` will now fetch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will request a file called "http" relative to the current path.

Answer (score 2):

The attribute `src="http"` refers to a resource with the relative URL `http`. Relative URLs are resolved relative to the current base URL, which is by default the URL of the document itself but can be set with a `base` element.

Resolution of relative URLs is normatively specified in [STD 66](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66). For example, if the URL of the document `http://www.example.com/foo/bar/fun.html` and there is no `base` element, then the attribute `src="http"` is equivalent to `src="http://www.example.com/foo/bar/http"`.

Answer (score 0):

With a colon that specifies the protocol that the rest of the mandatory url (uniform resource location), hyper text transport protocol in this case. Other types of protocol include https, ftp, ftps, mailto and more. At one time, gopher was "popular".

Without a colon, e.g. as asked, @recursive is correct.